# KeyError: 150L when accessing data in pandas DataFrame after dropping certain rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, keyerror

I have a function that iterates over a pandas DataFrame and drops rows that have a consecutive duplicate in a specific column. After that i try to return a running sum of that column in a list, but i seem to be getting a key error. I am not sure what this means.

Minimal Code:

```
dropRows = [] #stores rows indices to drop
#Sanitize the data to get rid of consecutive duplicates
for indx, val in enumerate(df.removeConsecutives): #for all the values
    if(indx == 0): #skip first indx
        continue

    if (val == df.removeConsecutives[indx-1]): #this is duplicate value as the last one
        dropRows.append(indx)

sanitizedData = df.drop(dropRows)

#Create Timestamps based on RTC
listOfSums= [0] #first sum is zero
sum = 0 #running total of seconds for timestamps
for indx, val in enumerate(sanitizedData.removeConsecutives):

    sum += sanitizedData.removeConsecutives[indx]

    listOfSums.append(sum) #add running sum to list
```

The error trace points to this line

```
    listOfSums.append(sum) #add running sum to list
```

And this is the error

```
C:\Users\JohnDoe\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\index.pyd in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas\index.c:2987)()

C:\Users\JohnDoe\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\index.pyd in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas\index.c:2802)()

C:\Users\JohnDoe\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\index.pyd in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:3528)()

C:\Users\JohnDoe\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\hashtable.pyd in pandas.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:7032)()

C:\Users\JohnDoe\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\hashtable.pyd in pandas.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:6973)()

KeyError: 150L
```

I am using iPython which installs all the packages (pandas, numpy, SciPy, etc on its own in one install file), so that s why the path says anaconda in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
for indx, val in enumerate(sanitizedData .band_rtc):
    sum += sanitizedData.removeConsecutives[indx]
```

You're using enumerate - i.e. your `indx` variable would go from 0 to the number of rows in sanitizedData. However, the `removeConsecutives` series **is not** indexed by consecutive numbers. Perhaps it used to - but not after you used `drop`.

Example - you had a df with 300 rows. Your found a duplicate at row 150, and dropped it. Now your df has 299 rows, indexed 0-149, 151-299. But `indx` goes from 0 to 298 - and tries to access 150! This would probably work if you'd use:

```
for indx, val in enumerate(sanitizedData .band_rtc):
    sum += sanitizedData.removeConsecutives.iloc[indx]
```

This is in regard to your question - but I recommend taking a look at [drop_duplicates](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) and [sum](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I don't understand how your solution works though, if - in your example - indx is 150 what does iloc do to return the corrent row now that indx 150 is gone?

Also the code i am using is minimal, i actually am doing something to the data before summing it but i ruled out what i was doing to it as a cause of the problem. So i cant really use the sum function, nor can i use drop duplicates as i need the duplicates to be consecutive.

Would iloc still fix my issue? Or do i need to reindex? And how would i reindex but keep the current order (skipping over dropped rows)

Comment: `iloc` accesses rows by location, so that 150th row in my example is located at 150, while its index is 151. I still think `iloc` would fix your issue, and if you want to reindex simply set `df.index` to something (range the size of your df, for example).